# create an instance of an object that conforms to a protocol given a class object with conforming to a protocol

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa, protocols

Suppose I define musicInfoDelegate protocol and create an object that conforms to musicInfoDelegate. In my Controller, I have the following class object that conforms to musicInfoDelegate. How do I create an instance of this class?

```
@property(strong,nonatomic)Class<musicInfoDelegate> myDelegate;
```

I try this

```
id object=[[myDelegate alloc] init];
```

the compiler tells me there is no alloc method in class myDelegate.

EDIT: Can anyone explain what situation we need to use class object with conforming to a protocol?(i.e. myDelegate)

Comment: Where do you assign a value to myDelegate?

Comment: @HotLicks: another view controller will initialize this controller, which will also assign myDelegate.

Comment: Assign what value to it?  And what is the actual compiler error message?

Answer (score 0):

```
@property (strong,nonatomic) Class myDelegate;
id<musicInfoDelegate> object = [[myDelegate alloc] init];
```